# Flutter ->Unable to set local path in audioplayer package

Tags: flutter, audio-player

i have 2 folders inside assets folder which is shown in image below i want to use icons and music in different folders but audioplayer is not working like it used to work when everything was in a single folder named assets but as soon as i changed it to 2 folders it has stopped working. [pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ3LM.png)[image showing folders view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtoww.png)

i have attached the code for audioplayer
earlier all the icons and music was in assets folder and in pubspec.yaml file I wrote assets/
it was working fine but as soon as i want to make 2 folders it stopped working and is giving errors

here milliseconds is a function which gives time in milliseconds and if widget.button_state is 'on' then i want to play music from local path.

the code->

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  Future<void> playDelayedSound() async {
    int delayInMilliseconds = miliseconds();


    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delayInMilliseconds),
            () async {
          if (widget.button_state == 'on') {
            await audioPlayer.play(
                AssetSource('assets/music/Luke-Bergs-Bliss.mp3'));
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

erros->

```
type here
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\shada\AndroidStudioProjects\clockw\.dart_tool\flutter_build\51129a8a9e24e7f0924f2f8bff077745\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\shada\AndroidStudioProjects\clockw\.dart_tool\flutter_build\51129a8a9e24e7f0924f2f8bff077745\kernel_snapshot.d
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ajs; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:721:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:861:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:660:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:99:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

just want to play the music which is inside assets/music folder
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to add the new asset path to your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: yes you can see the image of pubspec.yaml file i have attached.Can you tell me if i have made it wrong or what?